# How is `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` found by `java`?

Tags: java, junit

I have a junit java file `MyTest.java` which begins with

```
package steal;

import junit.framework.*;
```

After compiling it, I run it with

```
$ java -cp test:/somepath/to/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  MyTest
```

Is `/somepath/to/junit.jar` used for searching for

- `junit.framework.*` used in `MyTest`, and / or
- `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`?

If   `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` is not found by `/somepath/to/junit.jar`, how is `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` found by `java`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

> /somepath/to/junit.jar used for searching

both `junit.framework.*` and `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`

You are actually telling java that you want to execute your test with classpath provided, so java will scan this classpath for any imports from your test code.

You, probably, want to check this to learn more about Java Classpath: http://javapapers.com/java/java-classpath/

Comment: Thanks. which is `/somepath/to/junit.jar` used for searching for?

Comment: I understand classpath. I am asking how  `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` is found by `java`? Is `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` found under `/somepath/to/junit.jar` specified to `java -cp`?

Comment: Yes, I think, that `JUnitCore` is inside `junit.jar` and you can easily check it by unpacking `junit.jar` and go to the `org/junit/runner/` folder inside it.

Comment: Here you can see that `junit.jar` contains `JUnitCore`: [http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjunitjar.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjunitjar.htm)